# DeleteMany in mongoDb only deleting first condition data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to delete multiple rows in mongo db by multiple conditions but i see only first condition data is deleted. Please Someone help. Sharing the data for clarification.
Data:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("601fcc2f4bae4bc542085e8b"),
  "name": "tutoria 2",
  "id": 19,
  "rollno": 1020,
  "amount": "one hundred only"
}{
  "_id": ObjectId("601fce9a4bae4bc542085e8e"),
  "name": "tutoria 2",
  "id": 19,
  "rollno": 1020,
  "amount": "hundred only"
}{
  "_id": ObjectId("601fcea44bae4bc542085e8f"),
  "name": "tutoria 3",
  "id": 10,
  "rollno": 1020,
  "amount": "hundred only"
}{
  "_id": ObjectId("601fceb04bae4bc542085e90"),
  "name": "tutoria 4",
  "id": 21,
  "rollno": 1020,
  "amount": "hundred only"
}
```

Query:

```
db.movie.deleteMany(
{
  "name": "tutoria 4"
},
{
  "id": 10
}
)

{
  "acknowledged": true,
  "deletedCount": 1
}
```

Not sure what's wrong with mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

It worked by this.

```
db.movie.deleteMany({$or:[{"name":"tutoria 098"},{"id":20}]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.deleteMany({
  $and: [
    {name:"tutoria 4"},
    {id:10}
  ]
})
```

All matching query $and should return true to delete filtered documents, otherwise it won't delete at all.